# Laravel unbuffered queries are active error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-query-builder

I started to see this error the other day in my Laravel application. The weird thing is I haven't pushed any code changes up and it started to give this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

This is one of the queries it is complaining about:

```
public function addAgents($year)
{
    $result = DB::select("
        INSERT INTO {agents}
        (
            first_name,
            last_name,
            name
        )
        SELECT
        t.first_name,
        t.last_name,
        t.name
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
            first_name,
            last_name,
            CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name
            FROM {data_mart} d
            AND program_year = :year
        ) AS t
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        first_name = t.first_name,
        last_name = t.last_name,
        name = t.name,
    ", [':year' => $year]);
}
```

I am using: MariaDB 10.2.36

Would anyone have any recommendations on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB::select()` will expect to get a result set, and likely hangs things up waiting for one. Instead, [according to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-insert-statement), you should be using `DB::insert()` to perform an `INSERT` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up updating all the inserts deleted, and update queries with correlating functions and that fixed my issue. Still baffled how this worked for half a year like this.